# How to fix an Xbox 360 which freezes on the Xbox 360 logo when booting games?

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360

I have Xbox 360 Arcade. I connected all the cables properly, and to show that everything is working until this point, I get the following on my TV screen after connecting everything and starting the console:

[image: Xbox 360 home screen]

Now, as I insert the disk and close the tray - a disc which used to run on this same Xbox 7 years ago without any technical problems - First it displays "reading", then the screen gets black for few seconds and finally I get this on my TV screen:

[image: Xbox 360 logo screen - booting disk]

And then nothing happens, it stays like this as long as we please. I tried cleaning the tray, my disc is also clean and doesn’t have scratches. As I touch my console I get the vibration which advertises that disc is running (and hence reading machinery of XBOX is not faulty), the problem seem to be on displaying the things (I’m no expert).

How can I fix it? None of the discs are working.

Comment: It could be something wrong with the disc drive. If it hasn't been used in 7 years, perhaps the rails that move the laser have become gunked up. Or perhaps the laser itself needs a clean. If the disc and console worked 7 years ago (and they've otherwise been taken care of in storage over that period), it shouldn't be a huge problem to get it going again, but it might require some disassembly.

Comment: @Robotnik It seems a good conjecture. Should I disassemble it myself? If your conclusions are true then I should disassemble it just clean out everything.

Comment: I personally don't know enough about Xbox 360s to know how easy or difficult it is to disassemble or put back together, so I'm hesitant to send you down that path. There might be some way to clean the laser without disassembly though, using isopropyl alcohol and a q-tip/cotton swab. Failing that, a computer repair shop might be able to take a look?

Comment: @Robotnik Although Stack exchange prohibits politeness and etiquette, but then also I'm breaking the rules by saying "Thank You".